# ARKit little jumps during track

Tags: ios, swift, tracking, arkit

I've been using ARkit and I'm loving it, but I noticed that during load tracking can gut a little jumpy (suddenly objects jump from their position a little bit off, like 1-3 cms). I've been wondering if there's a way to smooth out these jumps so it wouldn't be so distracting. Here is a short video demonstrating it.
https://youtu.be/wmMBjlLyK7w

Comment: How are you adding the objects? Be sure to add an anchor if you don't want the objects to move

Answer (score 0):

I have been using ARKit and am also loving it I have been experiencing these issues as well and I have my theories but I am positive it is an issue with the hardware (comment which device you are using and I might be able to give a better estimate)

I believe it is the cameras on our devices and if that is the case then I would not worry about it too much because that would mean a behind the scenes problem we cant change or alter

If I'm not mistaken I remember Apple saying something about this in one of their developer classes earlier in this months keynote as I said before I wouldn't worry about it because older devices will have a harder time with the tracking because of the poorer cameras

Comment: Thanks, I’m using it with an iPhone 7, I guess the camera is not factory calibrated as on the newly released iPhones, but also I’m experiencing this issue more if I have a lot of objects around if I only have one or two it is not so appearent. So I thought maybe it could be an optimisation issue

Comment: then i dont know what the issue is. i know that tracking sucks on older devices (stuck with 5s here) so i figured that was the case but the 7 should be fine especially with the dual cameras maybe its an issue with your code